# Authorization Code Flow with PKCE - Using express backend 404

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

Express app running on http://localhost:6001 receiving requests from electron application on http://localhost:5000.

Authentication process:

**Authorization Code Flow with PKCE** - Authorizing the user(native app) and receive the authorization code in the url callback.

Decode it and then use it in the `POST /oauth/token`.

However, I'm receiving 404 error `"Request failed with status code 400"` when I call the `GET /authorize` endpoint.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import axios from 'axios';

const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const app = express();
var port = 6001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

app.get("/authorize", async (req: any, res: any, next:any) => {
  // Creates verifier 
  function base64URLEncode(str: Buffer) {
    return str.toString('base64')
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_')
      .replace(/=/g, '');
  }
  var verifier = base64URLEncode(crypto.randomBytes(32));
  // Generate a code_challenge
  function sha256(buffer: string) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(buffer).digest();
  }
  var challenge = base64URLEncode(sha256(verifier));
  // To mitigate replay attacks
  var nonce = nanoid();
  // Needs to be added locallty**

  await axios.get(`https://dev-49v8whrc.us.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&
        client_id=----------------------&
        prompt=none&
        connection=Username-Password-Authentication&
        redirect_uri=http://localhost:6001/authorize&
        nonce=${nonce}&
        code_challenge=${challenge}&
        code_challenge_method=S256`).then((authCode: any) => res.send(authCode) ).catch((err) => res.send(err))

});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean HTTP 400 error and not HTTP 404?

It's hard to pin point an exact reason from your question. It could be a number of things e.g. incorrect `client_id` querystring param.

A good way to debug this is to get the full `/authorize` URL that's being called (including all querystring params) and pasting this into a browser. You could get the full request URL using something like Fiddler.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I got all sorts of http errors. I think Im using the authorize endpoint incorrectly. I wanted to get auth code for  a username-password connection but I think the authorize is for identity providers although I could be wrong.

Comment: Using authorization code flow with PKCE; your public client apps should redirect to the (Auth0) `/authorize?...` endpoint (or open using in-app-browser-tab for native apps). Once the user has authenticated, the IDP would redirect back the specified `redirect_uri` (which would be private use URI scheme for native app). The public client app then calls the `/oauth/token?...` endpoint to exchange authorization code for tokens.

Comment: I will get back to this when I do the Google and Microsoft logins, Thanks for looking into this!